# Why my migration breaking visual studio?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm just messing around with entity framework code first and come with this set up:

My DataContext implements the follow interface:

```
 public interface IUnitOfWork
 {
     void Commit();
     IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class;
 }
```

as You can see here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47904

then in my DataContext I implement:

```
  public new IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class
  {
      return this.Set<T>();
  }
```

my Seed method:

```
 protected override void Seed(DATACONTEXT context)
 {
       context.Set<ENTITY>().AddOrUpdate(p => p.PROPERTY , new ENTITY
       {
           PROPERTY = VALUE
       });
 }
```

when I run the migration I get an Exception from visual studio.

Is there something wrong with my code? or its just a bug from visual studio?

Comment: What Exception do you get?

Comment: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version: 12.0.31101.0
  Application Timestamp: 54548724
  Fault Module Name: StackHash_199c
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000
  Exception Code: c00000fd
  Exception Offset: PCH_33
  OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 199c
  Additional Information 2: 199cc907df8a4654c8ebf31545ec3b64
  Additional Information 3: ac93
  Additional Information 4: ac932fb721b478be6e53cf5b63cba0e7

Comment: See if these steps solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640883/application-error-visual-studio-keeps-crashing