# Visual Studio 2015 keeps crashing on startup since Windows anniversary update

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crash, windows-10

I did an upgrade of Windows to the new anniversary update without losing my files (I chose to only get rid of my apps and settings). Everything went fine and I had Windows back with my files intact.

I decided to reinstall my apps and then it was time to install Visual Studio 2015 since I still had its ISO lying around. I mounted the image and started the installation, chose to install everything (**not custom**), it went smoothly and it was time to launch visual studio, I clicked on the launch button and visual studio launched but crashed on displaying the actual interface.

I was startled, I relaunched visual studio over and over again but it kept crashing with the classic Windows dialog.

`Visual Studio 2015 has stopped working`

Nothing to describe the error, absolutely nothing, I decided to do a clean uninstall of visual studio by force uninstalling it with IOBIT uninstaller which also deleted registry keys. I rebooted when that was done and decided to reinstall visual studio again the second time, same thing happened again.

I looked in the logs and found something interesting. It looks like it has something to do with Team Explorer starting when visual studio starts, but I'm not sure what's going on exactly.

**Relevant part of the logs**

```
<entry>
    <record>131</record>
    <time>2016/08/22 12:48:06.226</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Construction of frame content failed.&#x000D;&#x000A;Frame identifier: ST:0:0:{131369f2-062d-44a2-8671-91ff31efb4f4}&#x000D;&#x000A;Frame caption: Team Explorer&#x000D;&#x000A;Exception details:&#x000D;&#x000A;System.ArgumentException: Converter requires 11 source parameters.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.MultiValueConverterBase`1.ValidateConvertParameters(Object[] values, Type targetType)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio76.PlatformUI.MultiValueConverter`12.Convert(Object[] values, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.TransferValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.Transfer()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.UpdateTarget(Boolean includeInnerBindings)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.AttachOverride(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnAttach(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetInstanceValue(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElement feChild, FrameworkContentElement fceChild, Int32 childIndex, DependencyProperty dp, Int32 i, EffectiveValueEntry&amp; entry)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValueHelper(UncommonField`1 dataField, ItemStructList`1&amp; valueLookupList, DependencyProperty dp, DependencyObject container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex, Boolean styleLookup, EffectiveValueEntry&amp; entry, ValueLookupType&amp; sourceType, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValue(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, Int32 childIndex, FrameworkObject child, DependencyProperty dp, FrugalStructList`1&amp; childRecordFromChildIndex, EffectiveValueEntry&amp; entry, ValueLookupType&amp; sourceType, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetValueFromStyleOrTemplate(FrameworkObject fo, DependencyProperty dp, EffectiveValueEntry&amp; entry)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyStyleOrTemplateValue(FrameworkObject fo, DependencyProperty dp)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateContainerDependents(DependencyObject container, FrugalStructList`1&amp; exclusionContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1&amp; oldContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1&amp; newContainerDependents)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.DoThemeStyleInvalidations(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldThemeStyle, Style newThemeStyle, Style style)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateThemeStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldThemeStyle, Style newThemeStyle, Style&amp; themeStyleCache)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnThemeStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, Object oldValue, Object newValue)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetThemeStyle(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateThemeStyleProperty()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnInitialized(EventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.TryFireInitialized()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ChangeLogicalParent(DependencyObject newParent)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild(Object child)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged(Object oldContent, Object newContent)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry&amp; newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyStyleOrTemplateValue(FrameworkObject fo, DependencyProperty dp)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateContainerDependents(DependencyObject container, FrugalStructList`1&amp; exclusionContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1&amp; oldContainerDependents, FrugalStructList`1&amp; newContainerDependents)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.DoStyleInvalidations(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.UpdateStyleCache(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, Style oldStyle, Style newStyle, Style&amp; styleCache)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry&amp; newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.SetResourceReference(DependencyProperty dp, Object name)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Utility.SelectStyleForItem(FrameworkElement element, Object item, IExposeStyleKeys styleKeySource, Boolean deferIfInvisible)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsToolBar.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, Object item)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.MS.Internal.Controls.IGeneratorHost.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject container, Object item)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject container)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.GenerateChildren()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToolBarPanel.GenerateChildren()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.EnsureGenerator()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.get_InternalChildren()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToolBarPanel.MeasureGeneratedItems(Boolean asNeededPass, Size constraint, Boolean horizontal, Double maxExtent, Size&amp; panelDesiredSize, Double&amp; overflowExtent)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToolBarPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsToolBarPanel.MeasureWithCollapsePrevention(Size constraint)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsToolBarPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean&amp; hasDesiredSizeUChanged)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.ToolBar.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Controls.ToolBarTray.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.AdjustSearchControlPlacement()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.AddTopToolbarTray(VsToolWindowToolBarTray tray)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.AddToolbarTray(VsToolWindowToolBarTray tray, VSTWT_LOCATION location)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrameToolbarHost.OnToolbarTrayCreated(VsToolWindowToolBarTray newTray, VSTWT_LOCATION location)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.BaseToolbarHost.AddToolbar(UInt64 id, VSTWT_LOCATION location, IDropTarget dropTarget, IOleCommandTarget commandTarget, Boolean copyToolbarData)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.BaseToolbarHost.AddToolbar3(VSTWT_LOCATION location, Guid&amp; toolbarGuid, UInt32 toolbarId, IDropTarget dropTarget, IOleCommandTarget commandTarget)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, UInt32 flags)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.FindToolWindow(Type toolWindowType, Int32 id, Boolean create, ProvideToolWindowAttribute tool)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.CreateToolWindow(Guid&amp; toolWindowType, Int32 id)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsToolWindowFactory.CreateToolWindow(Guid&amp; toolWindowType, UInt32 id)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()</description>
  </entry>
```

**Full Logs [Here](https://gist.github.com/f3yisayo/0966019c148239102b69fe52659b7d65)**

I have tried launching Visual Studio with different flags:

`devenv /safemode`, `devenv /restsettings` and so on.

They all start with Visual Studio crashing on startup every time.

Comment: look in eventlog for details about the crash and pst the callstack that is logged there

Comment: @jessehouwing thank you so much for your comment, I tried repairing the installation and it didn't fix it. But I'll try downloading update 3 now and test if it fixes it.

Comment: @jessehouwing I have just installed update 3, The setup installed fine but completed with some errors and warnings, I managed to take a screenshot:  http://imgur.com/lLSpa3f but visual studio still crashes on startup, these are the new logs: https://gist.github.com/f3yisayo/8de73ed3aa931f55b9231cf4a9f504ad/raw/ae731905905b6b8fd5b57411df92e79a38f432aa/error2.txt

Comment: @jessehouwing thanks Jesse. I have actually tried that earlier and reinstalled from the ISO. But reinstalling fresh still doesn't fix VS. I am doing that again now and reinstalling afresh, is Update 3 supposed to be installed before I install the visual studio core?

Comment: @jessehouwing Quick question, does it matter that I'm installing VS after doing an upgrade of my Windows installation instead of clean install of Windows?

Comment: @jessehouwing OMG, I can't thank you enough Jesse, my VS finally works, in the order in which I did it. 1. I did a force uninstall of VS with vs_setup /uninstall /force from my mounted ISO directory. 2. I then uninstalled Visual studio from Control Panel > Program & Features then rebooted. 3. I reinstalled VS from the ISO all over again, I was prompted to do the initial setup, I did that and VS launched successfully! Thank you so much Jesse.    Can you post your suggestions as an answer so I can accept it as a solution to the problem?

Comment: 0x80200010 = BG_E_NETWORK_DISCONNECTED and downloading of file failed. use ISO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the installation got hosed, if the normal uninstaller isn't working, you can try a force uninstall using:

```
vs_setup /uninstall /force
```

Then reboot. Then try the installation again.

Given that you seem to have network issues when downloading the Update 3, try downloading the ISO instead of the download bootstrapper. Or create a local installation source first, to ensure you are getting all the right bits on your machine. You can create a local installation image using:

```
vs_setup /layout
```

If all else fails, see this post for more debugging tips:

- [Visual Studio keeps crashing: Application Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640883/application-error-visual-studio-keeps-crashing/15642027#15642027)