# Visual Studio Express 2013 crashes before launching

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

Since yesterday I've having issues with my Visual Studio Express 2013 for desktop: it crashes every time, no matter if I open a solution file or open VSE directly.
I've tried unistalling and reinstalling the software, with no avail.

I have the git integration tools for VS, so I don't know if the problem lays on there.

Comment: Does it show an error message when you try to open it?

Comment: @Froopy "An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in WDExpress.exe [2812]"

Comment: Have you tried removing git tools?  Also, is there a particular reason you wanna use 2013?  You could try installing 2015 Community.  If not, you may have luck with the steps outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15642027/6871531

Comment: @Froopy I have a very important project over there and I don't know if switching to a more recent version will bring compatibillity issues

Comment: [create a crash dump and analyze the dump with Windbg/DebugDiag2 Analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44312452/1466046). change reg key to wdexpress.exe instead of devenv.exe