# VS 2012 Crash in Tools/Choose toolbox items

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crash

I have taken below error at event viewer. What should I do?
Event viewer:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.50727.1, time stamp: 0x5011ecaa
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.8.3928.0, time stamp: 0x5d3900c0
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00332dd6
Faulting process id: 0x4c2c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5baf12ba718ab
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 3ec97926-9256-403d-a6e4-fe468a77749a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: The error message is too generic to help debug the issue. You can try the debugging steps described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15642027/259206) and update the question with the results, including call stacks and similar.

Answer (score 0):

The information is rather insufficient, but according to [this source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/06275c53-3a49-4376-98c0-8e28f3eaa853/faulting-application-name-devenvexe?forum=vssetup#2e61a893-01d9-4e89-9e0c-b658f72f42fb), it seems that `0xc0000005` exception code means "Access is denied", so you can probably try [running Visual Studio as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9654833/259206).